# Can't create objects within player class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, inheritance

Using visual studio 2015 enterprise. I've an Item class, Item.cpp. with Trying to assign the player a set item and have a vector for their unequipped items

```
class Player{

    #include "Player.h"

    Item items[3];
   vector<Item> storedItems;

}
```

I keep getting errors saying to define Item, but i've certainly still got the Item class there. When i try inheritance and make a 'Ring' class inherit item, it again will fail to find my definition of Item. I'm missing some key syntax here

Comment: `#include "Player.h"` statement is preprocessor command and will be replaces by  `"Player.h"` file content. You should place it outside class definition. `#include`s usually first lines in source files and headers.

Comment: Might I ask why you're burying a preprocessor `#include` in the **middle** of a class declaration ?

Comment: I was getting an error and it was removed by this.

Answer (score 1):

In Player.h make sure you have the Item.h include file at the top like:

```
#include "Item.h"
class Player {
    Item items[3];
    vector<Item> storedItems;
}
```

Comment: So if you are using objects of another class, you need to import the other class in the header file to use it?